# Office 365 Notable Events

Tags: office365, splunk

Do correlation searches in Splunk with Office365 events generate notable events in incident review?

I have created an alert to trigger on Office365 logs, there are events generating but on the incident review dashboard no notables are presented

Answer (score 0):

Not all correlation searches create notable events.  It is one of the actions which may be chosen when creating or editing a correlation search.

Comment: In this case notable events were selected as an adaptive response action